# Printing values of a certain order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array `A` and I want to print number of values which are of the order: `1e2` and also the specific values.

I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([ 4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,
        4.22134987e+02, -7.07598661e-11, -6.80734822e-11,  8.24084601e-11])

B=A[A==1e2]
print(B)
```

The current output is

```
[]
```

The expected output is

```
[5,4.22134987e+02]
```

Comment: Where has `5` come from in the output? Why are you doing `==` when clearly you would want `>=`?

Comment: @roganjosh. Seems to be the count?

Comment: I'm guessing so, but while I was typing it was updated from `4` to `5`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "*of the order: 1e2*"? What is the exact range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1e2` is `100.00`

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([ 4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,
        4.22134987e+02, -7.07598661e-11, -6.80734822e-11,  8.24084601e-11])

B=A[A>=1e2]  #or B=A[A>=100]
[len(B),*set(B)]

#output
[5, 422.134987]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be A>=1e2 and SA<1e3 ?

Answer (score 2):

One option using transformation to [`log10`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html), [`ceil`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html) and [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the values in the range `[100-1000[`

```
np.unique(A[np.ceil(np.log10(A)) == 2+1], return_counts=True)
```

Output: `(array([422.134987]), array([5]))`

Comment: You don't have a warning for np.log10(A) (for -7.07598661e-11)?

Comment: @Corralien you can pre-filter the values close to 0 if needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
tol = 8  # tolerance
m = (1 <= A/1e2) & (A/1e2 < 10)
B = A[m]
B = (len(B), list(np.unique(B.round(tol))))
```

Output:

```
>>> B
(5, [422.134987])

>>> m
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

The "of the order" is relative, because of which one should specify how close to 1e2 is desired. One way amongst many to do that is to define a factor, say `fac` here, so that the range of (100./fac, 100*fac) will be accepted:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([ 4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,  4.22134987e+02,
        4.22134987e+02, -7.07598661e-11, -6.80734822e-11,  8.24084601e-11])

fac=5.
B=A[np.where((A<fac*1e2) & (A>1e2/fac))]
print('-'*50)
print('B: ', B)
print('-'*50)
print('count: ', len(B))
print('-'*50)
print('[count, set(B)]: ', [len(B),*set(B)])
print('-'*50)
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------
B:  [422.134987 422.134987 422.134987 422.134987 422.134987]
--------------------------------------------------
count:  5
--------------------------------------------------
[count, set(B)]:  [5, 422.134987]
--------------------------------------------------
```